# HP 255 G6 freezing at random times with Ubuntu

Tags: hp, acpi, compatibility

The problem is that after installing Linux distribution, Laptop freezes at random times, and it is not related to opening a specific program, I can do nothing to it except for a force-shutdown by holding the power button.

During the boot of distribution a similar ACPI error message appeared:

```
Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI Warning for \_SB_._OSC: Return
type mismatch - found Integer, expected Buffer
(20090903/nspredef-1006)

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI Error (psargs-0359): [ECEN]
Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI Error (psparse-0537): Method
parse/execution failed [\] (Node ffffffff81f08530), AE_NOT_FOUND

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI Error (dswload-0659): [PCI0]
Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During
name lookup/catalog (20090903/psloop-230)

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI Error (psparse-0537): Method
parse/execution failed [\] (Node ffffffff81f08530), AE_NOT_FOUND

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI: Executed 3 blocks of module-level
executable AML code

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI: Interpreter enabled

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI: (supports S0 S5)

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI: BIOS offers _GTS

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI: If "acpi.gts=1" improves suspend,
please notify linux-acpi@vger.kernel.org

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt
routing

Oct 23 19:44:52 dhcp33 kernel: ACPI Warning: Incorrect checksum in
table [OEMB] - 16, should be 11 (20090903/tbutils-314)
```

Comment: Only proper question and answer format is allowed here. I have separated "problem" part and "solution" (rather "explanation") part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yousef,
I had the same issue with Linux Mint 18.03 Sylvia and the HP 255 G6 and like you it kept freezing up, also whilst in the boot up phase I noticed a lot of ACPI warnings and some garbled screeen images. It would then allow me to log in and then freeze.

I tried various things and none worked so I wiped the disk and installed Ubuntu 18.04 Mate and that has worked like a charm. I left it running overnight last night and it's still up and running this morning and no issues so far.

I didn't install any proprietory drivers on Ubuntu Mate where I did install the AMD Microcode on Mint whether this had any bearing I don't know?

I was reading elsewhere that the reason the latest Ubuntu may work is because the Kernel version in this release is higher and includes different drivers that work better with this laptop??

Siv

Comment: That's great news, I hope you are right.
When I had the laptop, I tried Ubuntu 18.04, but during the boot same ACPI error message appeared.
If you encounter freezing on the distribution, please share :). Thanks a lot, sir.

Comment: Yousef - The laptop is now with the client and she has had no issues with it freezing and has been using it today. My only issue is finding out how to adjust the screen brightness as there does not seem to be a slider in settings to do this??

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this post to clarify to other Linux users that *HP 255 G6* Laptop is incompatible with Ubuntu -and probably any other Linux distribution.

I searched the error message above, found out that it's related to BIOS errors, but that freeze won't occur with Windows OS, as Windows provides its own "ACPI tables" -as I read somewhere-, and since the majority of end users use Windows, companies care about testing for bugs with Windows not other OSes.

- I tried both CSM and UEFI modes.
- I tried to update the BIOS to latest version.
- I tried flags `acpi=off`, `nomodeset`, but also in vain, actually it became worse, I heard weird sounds from the laptop.

Resources:

https://access.redhat.com/articles/65378 - shows the meaning of ACPI error message.